# When i add Firebase Realtime database in my app it start crashing

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add a Firebase realtime database into my Android App. It works fine until I add

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
```

in my Gradle (module:App) to add a Firebase Real-time database. After adding this my App crashes on start. Firstly It shows a crash error saying"Start the App again" and after clicking on it crashes again and says "close the App".
I have tried to search on google but could not find an answer to this particular problem.
Can anybody give any hints?
Here are all the gradle dependencies

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

}
```

Here is a part of log file which is in red color:

```
--------- beginning of crash
2020-03-11 18:45:31.616 6390-6390/com.example.firebasechat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.firebasechat, PID: 6390
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setTokenProvider(Lcom/google/firebase/internal/InternalTokenProvider;)V in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.firebasechat-1/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzp.create(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.lambda$new$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:69)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.initializeEagerComponents(com.google.firebase:firebase-components@@16.0.0:158)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeAllApis(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:563)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:304)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:268)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:253)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@19.3.0:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5811)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5403)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5342)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

2020-03-11 18:45:31.961 6390-6409/com.example.firebasechat W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
2020-03-11 18:45:32.056 6390-6409/com.example.firebasechat I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
2020-03-11 18:45:32.056 6390-6409/com.example.firebasechat I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Comment: Where is your error? Please post logcat

Comment: can you add your crash log

Comment: Try adding the configuration file. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @PratikButani Log cat is added. It is quite long so i added only the lines which are in red color. Please let me know if all the entries are needed.
Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to show all of the dependencies in your build.gradle.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have included all the dependencies above. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure all of your Firebase libraries are up to date with each other.  It is often not possible to mix and match versions with each other.  The latest versions are all shown in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  Right now, your firebase-auth dependency is rather old.  It should be 19.2.0.

Docs Provided proper information about MAJOR version update on [June 2019](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17)

Comment: Updating firebase-auth to 19.2.0 solved the problem. Thanks!